# How to display an ant patternset

Tags: ant

I'm trying to display an ant patternset for debugging purposes. In my sample the patternset is displayed as dontcompile patternSet{ includes: [] excludes: [] }, no info from the excludesfile is shown.

I know the excludesfile is working because on Linux no windows sources are shown at the end.

build.xml

```
<project default="init" >

    <condition property="osname" value="linux">
        <os family="unix" />
    </condition>
    <!-- if it's not unix assume it's some kind of windows -->
    <property name="osname" value="windows" />

    <target name="init" >

        <local name="dont_compile.os.present" />
        <local name="dont_compile.present" />
        <available file="dont_compile.${osname}.lst" property="dont_compile.os.present" />
        <available file="dont_compile.lst" property="dont_compile.present" />

        <echo>dont_compile.${osname}.lst ${dont_compile.os.present}${line.separator}dont_compile.lst ${dont_compile.present}</echo>
        <patternset id="dontcompile">
            <excludesfile name="dont_compile.${osname}.lst" if="dont_compile.os.present" />
            <excludesfile name="dont_compile.lst" if="dont_compile.present" />
        </patternset>

        <fileset id="myfileset" dir=".">
            <include name="**/*.source" />
            <patternset refid="dontcompile" />
        </fileset>

<loadfile property="os_contents" srcFile="dont_compile.${osname}.lst" />
        <local name="ps.value" />
        <property name="ps.value" refid="dontcompile" />

        <echo>
dontcompile ${ps.value}"
os_contents ${os_contents}
${toString:myfileset}
</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

contents of dont_compile.linux.lst

```
windows.source
win/**
```

contents of my test directory

```
./build.xml
./dont_compile.linux.lst
./general.source
./linux.source
./windows.source
./win/sub.source
```

sample output

```
Buildfile: build.xml

init:
     [echo] dont_compile.linux.lst true
     [echo] dont_compile.lst ${dont_compile.present}
     [echo]
     [echo] dontcompile patternSet{ includes: [] excludes: [] }"
     [echo] os_contents windows.source
     [echo] win/sub.source
     [echo]
     [echo] general.source;linux.source

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: patternSet{ includes: [] excludes: [windows.source, win/**] }

Comment: I gave this a try myself and it seems that Ant doesn't support this, unfortunately. The contents of the patternset will print out if you specify `includes` and `excludes` directly in the code, but if they are defined with an `includesfile` or `excludesfile` the set will always print as empty (even though it works as intended for actual file operations).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455252/how-to-display-an-ant-patternset-containing-an-excludesfile